# Dominated convergence theorem on random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I currently working on a paper and I have the following problem:

Let $X$ be a random vector on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with distribution $\alpha$. Define $\alpha_\varepsilon:=\frac{1}{Z_\varepsilon}\cdot\alpha \cdot\exp(-\frac{1}{2} \varepsilon \lVert x\rVert^2)$, where $Z_\varepsilon:= \int\alpha \cdot\exp(-\frac{1}{2} \varepsilon \lVert x\rVert^2) dx$, so that $\alpha_\varepsilon$ is again a probability distribution. Let $X_\varepsilon$ be a random vector with density $\alpha_\varepsilon$.
Further we have a unit vector $\eta \in \mathbb{R^n}$ and a (positive semi-definite) matrix $H\in \mathbb{R^{n \times n}}.$

Now the statement in the paper is the following:
\begin{equation}
 \lim_{\varepsilon \searrow 0}\mathbb{P}(\langle \eta, H(X_\varepsilon) \eta \rangle\leq t) = \mathbb{P}(\langle \eta, H(X) \eta \rangle\leq t).
\end{equation}
How can I prove this? Apparently this is due the the dominated convergence theorem but I have no idea how to apply it here.
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Try to prove that $Z_\varepsilon\to 1$; the argument for $\alpha_\varepsilon$ is the same (and you will need the convergence of $Z_\varepsilon$ for this anyway).

Comment: I did prove $Z_\varepsilon \rightarrow 1$ by applying the dominated convergence theorem to the sequence $\alpha(x) \cdot \exp(-\frac{1}{2} \varepsilon \lVert x \rVert^2)$. This series converges pointwise to $\alpha(x)$ and is also bounded by $\alpha(x)$. Thereby I can apply the dominated convergence theorem and state that $\lim_{\varepsilon \searrow 0}Z_\varepsilon = \int \alpha(x)dx =1$.

There I had a sequence of functions ($\alpha(x) \cdot \exp(-\frac{1}{2} \varepsilon \lVert x \rVert^2)$) but in the given problem I don't even know what sequence I can apply the theorem to.

Comment: I mean maybe I could consider $\langle \eta, H(X_\varepsilon) \eta \rangle$ as a series of functions $\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. But then I would need to show that this series converges pointwise to  $\langle \eta, H(X) \eta \rangle$ and I don't think it does, or does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that your convergence is the same as saying that the r.v. $\omega \mapsto Y_\varepsilon(\omega):=\langle \eta, H(X_\varepsilon(\omega)) \eta\rangle$ converges in distribution (or weakly). This in turn, by the portmanteau lemma, is equivalent to
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} \mathbb{E}[f( Y_\varepsilon)] = \mathbb{E}[ f(Y)],
$$
for every bounded continuous function $f$. On the other hand, notice that
$$
f(Y_\varepsilon)= f(\langle \eta, H(X_\varepsilon)\eta\rangle) =: F(X_\varepsilon),
$$
where $F(x)= \langle \eta, H(x)\eta\rangle$, and so if $H$ is a bounded, continuous matrix valued function, then $F$ is bounded and continuous as well, and so, since $X_\varepsilon\to X$ in distribution (this is where DCT comes in), the result follows.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I am not sure if I understood it correcctly though. So the proof would go like this?
\begin{align}
\alpha(X_\varepsilon) \rightarrow \alpha(X) \\
\Rightarrow X_\varepsilon \rightarrow X \mathrm{in \;distribution. \;(By\;Scheffe's \;Lemma???)}\\
\Rightarrow \mathbb{E}(F(X_\varepsilon)) \rightarrow \mathbb{E}(F(X))
 \;\forall \mathrm{bounded \;continous \;F}. \mathrm{(By\; portmanteau)} \\

\end{align}

Comment: \begin{align}
\Rightarrow  \mathbb{E}(F(X_\varepsilon)) \rightarrow \mathbb{E}(F(X))
 \;\\\forall \mathrm{\;F \;of\; the\; form\;} F(x)= f(\langle \eta, H(x)\rangle) \mathrm{ with\;}f\mathrm{\; bounded\;and\;continous\;}\\
\Rightarrow  \mathbb{E}(F(Y_\varepsilon)) \rightarrow \mathbb{E}(F(Y)) \\
\Rightarrow Y_\varepsilon \rightarrow Y \mathrm{\;in\;distribution \;(By\;portmanteau)}
\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(Y_\varepsilon \leq t) \rightarrow \mathbb{P}(Y\leq t)
\end{align}

But I still don't see where I use the dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: @maiktheissen: You use DCT in the very first step, in proving that $X_\varepsilon\to X$ in distribution (or rather that the densities converge weakly): $$\mathbb{E}[F(X_\varepsilon)]=\int F(x)\alpha_\varepsilon(x)\, dx$$, which has the right limit by the DCT.